# Function Spaces: How do I show that $\|x(t)\|=\sup\{|x(t)|:t \text{ contained in }I\} $ satisfies the three conditions of Absolsute Value Thm?

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently taking Real Analysis 2 (a.k.a Advanced Calc 2) and have been assigned the following question:

Let I be any set, and let B(I)  be the set of all bounded real-valued functions on I. An absolute value can be defined on B(I) by the formula
\begin{align*}
\|x\|=\sup\{|x(t)|\ :\ t\in I\}, 
\end{align*}
and then a distance by the formula $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$.

Show that the absolute value just defined satisfies:

a.) $\|x\|\geq0$, and $\|x\|=0$ only if $x=0$.

b.) $\|a\cdot x\|=|a|\cdot \|x\|$ if $a$ is a real number

c.) $\|x+y\|\leq\|x\|+\|y\|$.

There is another part to this question having to do with the specified d(x,y) satisfying some other rules, but at this point I am just looking for some direction rather than anybody answering the question for me:)

My thoughts on this: I guess I am thrown of a bit now because I am dealing with functions. I looked back at the definition of supremum and found the following axiom:

"Every non-empty set of real numbers has a least upper bound." With this axiom alone I conclude that $\|x\|\geq0$, and $\|x\|=0$ only if $x=0$. So a is satisfied and there is nothing left to show. Do you agree?

I should mention that I am still looking at $\|x\|$ as a real-valued vector and not so much as a function (I guess). I am interpreting the difference between $|x|$ and $\|x\|$ to simply be a way of distinguishing two different norms, one based on $\langle x,x\rangle$ and the other on the Supremum.

Part B: This seems so trivial that I can't think of a way to show that this is true.

Just a bit lost so any help would be appreciated.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

a) No. The axiom, you mentioned, just guarantees that the supremum of the set $\{|x(t)|\ :\ t\in I\}$ exists. It does not show that $||x||\geq0$ or anything else.

Ok. We have to show that $||x||\geq0$. Note that $|x(t)|\geq0$ for each $t\in I$, since the absolute value is nonnegative. Thus, the supremum over all those values must be nonnegative as well, which shows $||x||\geq0$. 
Now, let $||x||=0$ for some bounded function $x$. By definition, this means that $\sup\{|x(t)|\ :\ t\in I\}=0$ (so the maximal value of the function $|x|$ is 0). This implies $|x(t)|=0$ for each $t\in I$, and we conclude that $x(t)=0$ for each $t\in I$. Note that $|\cdot|$ is a norm on the set of real numbers, so it satisfies $|a|=0\ \Leftrightarrow a=0$ for $a\in\mathbb R$.

b) This is indeed not difficult. Just use that $|a\cdot x(t)|=|a||x(t)|$ for each $t\in I$, and that $\sup\{ |a b|\ : b\in B\}=|a|\sup\{|b|\ : b\in B\}$, whenever $B\subset\mathbb R$.

c) Try this on your own first and don't hesitate to ask if you get stuck somewhere.

Comment: Hey,thanks for the prompt reply. I am working on it right now.

Comment: Ok. Here are my thoughts on part C.)

Comment: I say let x(t) and y(t) be some real-valued bounded functions with t contained in I. Then, if x(t) and y(t) have the same maxima, the triangle inequality says that |x(t)+y(t)|=|x(t)|+|y(t)|. If x(t) and y(t) have different maxima, then |x(t)+y(t)|<=

Comment: First, be careful with your notation. $x(t)$ means that you have a function $x$ and evaluate it at $t$, so $x(t)$ is a real number. Moreover, what does the triangle inequality say about $|x(t)+y(t)|$?

Comment: Ok. So you are saying that I should say x and y because this would mean just functions not evaluated at any particular point? Then, I am thinking of this problem in terms of the functions' x and y maxima. I am trying to justify the statement "if x and y maxima occur at different points, then |x+y|<=|x|+|y|."

Comment: Before commenting, give me one second because I'm in the middle of  thought:)

Comment: So, is |x+y|<=|x|+|y| saying that |"All the values of X"+"All the values of y"|<=|"All the values of x"|+|"All the values of y"|?

Comment: I think you are still not clear when to use $|\cdot|$ and when $||\cdot||$. $|\cdot|$ does only make sense for real numbers (it is just the absolute value), where $||\cdot||$ only make sense for functions (it is just the maximum of the function in absolute values). This means: if $x$ and $y$ are functions (you are right, just $x$ and $y$, not $x(t)$ or $y(t)$), then you have to prove $||x+y||\leq||x||+||y||$. But to prove this, you can use the triangle inequality for real numbers $|x(t)+y(t)|\leq|x(t)|+|y(t)|$ for each $t\in I$, because this occurs in the definition of the norm $||\cdot||$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your all your help. It has been super useful. I moved on from that problem without solving it, but I am coming back to it now. I only need to show part c to finish the whole problem. My problem is with the following statement:

Comment: Sup{|x(t)+y(t)|:t cont I}<=Sup{|x(t)|:teI}+Sup{|y(t)|:teI}. Let us clarify this statement a bit because I believe that this is what my next big problem is. I am interpreting this statement as saying that "at each teI, the inequality holds." So lets say x(t)=Y(t)=3 for a specific value of t.

Comment: I guess I don't get it. I can't justify |x(t)+y(t)|≤|x(t)|+|y(t)| for each t∈I to my self. If both x(t) and y(t) are positive real numbers for a particular t,then the Triangle inequality is just an equivalence statement. If x(t) is positive and y(t) is negative for a particular t, then the statement is true. That is how I am understanding the statement the triangle inequality is making. Also, I see this statement as being checked at each t.

Comment: Hey Andrew, to avoid too long comments, just contact me via email. It would be a pleasure to help you further.

Comment: So, in this case |x(t)|=a real # and |y(t)|=a real # at each specified teI. I know this might make me sound dumb, but I have been hit with several definitions in the last week and I think I am starting to see dead people:)